# Stop Overwriting SonarQube Existing job results

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am running a job through Jenkins with the SonarQube Execute Scanner Plugin.

These are all my Analysis Properties

```
sonar.projectKey=Project1
sonar.projectName=ProProject
sonar.projectVersion=Layer1
sonar.verbose=true
sonar.sources=src
sonar.qualitygate=SonarQube way 
sonar.libraries=lib
sonar.tests=Tests
sonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true
sonar.issuesReport.console.enable=true 
sonar.includePlugins=views,report,buildbreaker
sonar.analysis.mode=publish
sonar.issuesReport.console.enable=true
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

When I try to view SonarQube results for my sonar jobs, I see that the result of previous job is being overwritten with the new job.

I am loosing my previous job result

Comment: Yep. That's how it works.

Answer (score 3):

That's the default behavior of this plugin and of SonarQube. If you want to see changes over time in your project's code quality and issues (UI of SonarQube 5.6.2):

- go to your SonarQube instance,
- click on the name of the project you're interested it,
- under the project name, there will be a menu: click on Dashboards -> TimeMachine.

You'll see graphs showing changes in the number of issues, lines of code, test coverage, and so on. In the top right, you should be able to choose a time frame you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks I think this will help @ameba